# Excel - Find Highest Value of Text String in Group/Array (Pic)

Tags: excel

So my head hurts trying to make this work after researching and through trial and error (mostly error). Its probably something simple that I'm missing.

I have a column that displays a text string with letters and numbers. The value is always a total of 13 characters with the last two as numerical digits (i.e. 01, 02, 03, etc.). I would like the adjacent column to indicate which row contains the largest value (based on the last 2 numerical values) in that group (see image).

[image: Excel Screenshot]

I found a similar example but can't get it working in my application ([Excel - Find Highest Value of a Column in all Matching Rows (With Screenshot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459534/excel-find-highest-value-of-a-column-in-all-matching-rows-with-screenshot)). Not sure if it is because of cell formatting.

Please help--It is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use the **Right()** Formula to extract the last two digits from each text string, if A2 is the  cell containing the text string **Right(A2,2)** would return the last 2 digits, but not as number, to convert them to number you can nest the Right() formula like this **NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(A2,2))**. You will get the last two digits as number. Now you can use the **MAX()** formula on the resulting number column to decide on the largest value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with an array formula:

```
=IF(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(A2,2))=MAX(IF(LEFT($A$2:$A$10,11)=LEFT(A2,11),NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT($A$2:$A$10,2)))),TRUE)
```

You need to hit ctrl+shift+enter after entering the formula. It assumes 13-character strings with 2 digits at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I can show you how to do this piecemeal...  if you add the following formulas, it should do what you seek.

1. In Cell B2, enter the formula `=LEFT(A2,11)`
2. In Cell C2, enter `=RIGHT(A2,2)+0`.  The `+0` is actually important because it takes the context of the value from text to numeric, which will allow the next part to work
3. In Cell D2, you want an array formula.  Type in `=MAX(IF($B:$B=B2,$C:$C))`, and when you hit enter, **hold down CTRL and SHIFT**.  If you do it correctly, when you are on the cell, Excel will have { braces } around your formula (even though you won't see them when you try to edit)
4. Cell E2 is now simply `=C2=D2`

When you copy your formulas down, I believe it will have the desired result:

```
TEXTXXXXXXX01   TEXTXXXXXXX 1   3   FALSE
TEXTXXXXXXX02   TEXTXXXXXXX 2   3   FALSE
TEXTXXXXXXX03   TEXTXXXXXXX 3   3   TRUE
TEYTYYYYYYY04   TEYTYYYYYYY 4   5   FALSE
TEYTYYYYYYY05   TEYTYYYYYYY 5   5   TRUE
TEZTZZZZZZZ06   TEZTZZZZZZZ 6   10  FALSE
TEZTZZZZZZZ07   TEZTZZZZZZZ 7   10  FALSE
TEZTZZZZZZZ08   TEZTZZZZZZZ 8   10  FALSE
TEZTZZZZZZZ09   TEZTZZZZZZZ 9   10  FALSE
TEZTZZZZZZZ10   TEZTZZZZZZZ 10  10  TRUE
```